# (Android) Draw image outside the view class (canvas access?)

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw

I'd like to make a Library containing an override class of View(eg: MyView extends View)
and want to make a method "Draw(String FileName)".

So what I ultimately want to do is to simply import this library and call this "Draw(String FileName)" method to draw an image from other activities.

I've tried by myself, but I encountered some problem with accessing main Canvas which onDraw() method actually has.

It would be easy if I just draw every image in onDraw() method function,
but I have no idea how to put things from outside the class.

any idea for this structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved my problem but I'm not sure this is the best way.

I made an interface call back function inside the class which inherits `View`,
and I could access the `Draw()` method by using that call back.